# The CPU skyrockets when i launch a node

Tags: ros, python, ros-melodic, cpu

[image: Rosanswers logo]

**Hello wise people of the Ros Answers realm,**

I have a node that performs a random walk.In order to get the information i need(pose,laser readings etc) and keep my code somewhat clean, i created  2 classes which, i instanciate passing as an argument the namespace of the robot(robot_1,robot_2 etc). In the init function of the first class i start an odom subscriber and a cmd_vel publisher while in the other class i just subscribe to the /namespace/laser_scan topic.

I launch the said node for 4-5 robots in the stage simulator and everything seem to work fine.The node is runing correctly but the  cpu usage skyrockets at 100% on all cores.This happens only when i launch this node for multiple robots.
Why is this happening?Im sure that i am missing something but i cant figure out what it is.
Thanks in advance.

The links to the node and  classes.

[Robot_Class](https://github.com/NickTziaros/random_walk/blob/master/src/robot_class.py)

[Laser_Class](https://github.com/NickTziaros/random_walk/blob/master/src/laser_class.py)

[Random_Walk_Node](https://github.com/NickTziaros/random_walk/blob/master/src/rw_node.py)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/389291/the-cpu-skyrockets-when-i-launch-a-node./) by [Nick_JR](https://answers.ros.org/users/56383/nick_jr/) on ROS Answers with karma: 37 on 2021-10-22

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [osilva](https://answers.ros.org/users/84086/osilva/) on 2021-10-23**:
Hi Nick_JR would you be able to give more details on your hardware setup otherwise it’s hard to say. There are many factors your memory, if you have a GPU and your simulation is using it. Each robot is like opening a new session of the simulator -not quite but the simulator has to run all processes for each robot simultaneously

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

One issue is that your `while` loops (in main() and fix_yaw()) are executing as fast as the cpu core can run. The proper fix is to sleep() inside these loops. Unless you have a very good reason, don't execute those loops more than 100 times a second.

You can use a rospy::Rate object to publish to cmd_vel with (mostly) fixed period. It depends on your hardware, but 10 or 20 Hz is usually fast enough for cmd_vel.

---

Originally posted by [Mike Scheutzow](https://answers.ros.org/users/75154/mike-scheutzow/) with karma: 4903 on 2021-10-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1